# Crear ComboBox en las celdas de Excel con VBA (no con UserForm)

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo una duda, soy un poco novato con Visual Basic para Excel pero he hecho cositas, sin embargo ahora tengo una duda.

Primero quiero crear un Select o Lista desplegable o ComboBox (Como quieran llamarlo) pero no quiero hacerlo con UserForm pues este me despliega una ventana sobre las celdas y lo quiero es en las celdas. **Ejemplo (Ver imagen)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Porque creo que necesito que sea visual basic porque lo que quiero es que por ejemplo al seleccionar **PERRO** en la celda no quede la palabra perro sino un 1, o si es **GATO** que sea el numero 2, **VACA** numero 3.

Me hago entender?

Espero puedan ayudarme

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

esta fue la respuesta que llegue para solucionar:

Primero en una hoja cree en una columna la lista de datos y en otra al frente el numero que le corresponde(El numero es solo referencia): (Ver imagen)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego desde DESARROLLADOR/INSERTAR/CONTROLES DE FORMULARIO
Inserto un ComboBox y click derecho sobre el, alli selecciono FORMATO DE CONTROL y le asigno la lista de articulos y luego con que celda lo quiero vincular, de esta manera al seleccionar un articulo, en la celda vinculada se muestra la posicion de ese elemento en la lista en la celda seleccionada. Asi: (Ver imagen)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que esto le sirva a alguien mas. Suerte!

Answer (score 0):

La característica que estás buscando aplicar a la celda se llama [validación de datos](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/aplicar-la-validaci%C3%B3n-de-datos-a-celdas-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249).

Comment: Gracias he buscado por este medio y encontre la opcion.

Comment: Si la opción que encontraste es la que mencioné, podrías aceptar mi respuesta. Ref. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien responde mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Si encontraste una solución diferente podrías publicar una respuesta con tu solución.

Comment: Es que no fue lo mas descriptiva que digamos, sin embargo leyendo y otras preguntas logre llegar a algo muy parecido a lo que queria, pero sin necesidad de usar VBA.

Comment: @JuanFernandez Si por eso mismo dije "podrías" y no "deberías". Por otro lado ¿cómo se llama eso a lo que llegaste sin usar VBA?

Comment: Ya he dejado como lo solucione en una respuesta. Saludos!

Comment: @JuanFernandez No olvides aceptar tu respuesta.